# Why this modrewrite rule not having an redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apache Version: **Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)**

I have the following rewrite rule defined in `.htaccess` file

`RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]`

And it is working fine (means it is reaching index.php of goto folder). But my thought in this that it should generate a redirect loop.

Suppose a url is `http://example.com/goto/foo`. So in first iteration it will have `http://example.com/goto/index.php?q=foo`. In second iteration it should match rewriterule `goto/(.*)` and should have a redirect loop.

My question is how it avoiding the redirect loop?

My .htacces file contains only the folwwing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And inside goto folder there is only index.php. No other files there.

**EDIT**

I have also tested this using wamp 2.2
Apache version 2.2.2

Below is the rewrite log

```
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/ddfd -> goto/ddfd
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] applying pattern '^goto/(.*)$' to uri 'goto/ddfd'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] rewrite 'goto/ddfd' -> 'goto/index.php?q=ddfd'
split uri=goto/index.php?q=ddfd -> uri=goto/index.php, args=q=ddfd
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] add per-dir prefix: goto/index.php -> D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] strip document_root prefix: D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/index.php -> /test/blog/goto/index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] internal redirect with /test/blog/goto/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/index.php -> goto/index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] applying pattern '^goto/(.*)$' to uri 'goto/index.php'
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] rewrite 'goto/index.php' -> 'goto/index.php?q=index.php'
split uri=goto/index.php?q=index.php -> uri=goto/index.php, args=q=index.php&q=ddfd
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] add per-dir prefix: goto/index.php -> D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/index.php
[perdir D:/wamp/www/test/blog/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: D:/wamp/www/test/blog/goto/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Last entry says it is IGNORING REWRITE. So what configuration is actually instructing to ignore rewrite in this case?

Comment: From documentation, `The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set.` [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#page-header)

Comment: @HussainTamboli But the `[L]` flag in `.htaccess` will only stop the current cycle. It will return what it currently has rewritten, the invokes `.htaccess` again over and over again until the url stops changing.

Comment: @chanchal118: My guess is that you might have `goto/.htaccess` also OR some other in current .htaccess which is rewriting this.

Comment: If you don't get an error, check your `httpd.conf` file.

Comment: @Sumurai8 My apache version is Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) . Which configuration/directive in apache2.conf i should look for?

Comment: @chanchal118: Is this .htaccess even being read? Are you seeing content of `goto/index.php?q=foo` ?

Comment: @anubhava yes, i have printed the value of `q` and it is displayed.

Comment: Can you enable `RewriteLog` to investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

On my setup, this rule indeed causes an infinite loop. It will eventually give a `500 Internal Error`, because it exceeds the maximum amount of internal redirects. In `.htaccess` the `[L]` flag will only stop the current cycle of rewrites to stop, but it won't stop a new cycle from happening. It will only stop if the url stops changing. *(This is different behaviour than in `httpd.conf` when not in per-directory context where the `[L]` flag will stop rewriting completely)*

There are a couple of ways you can stop the infinite loop.

```
#1. Any url with index.php in it will not be rewritten
RewriteRule index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Every url with index.php in it will match the first rule. Because the url is not rewritten, it will not initiate a new cycle.

```
#2. Exclude 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/goto/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Use a condition to check if index.php is not in the current url

```
#3. Use the END flag
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Use the `END` flag. Please note that this flag is only available from Apache 2.3.9 and up. It will stop rewriting completely in `.htaccess` context.

Comment: however, you don't explain why there is no infinite loop in the OP's setup, or do you?

Comment: It would not generate an infinite loop if there is an other rule that is working on `/goto/index.php` or the system-specific implementation of Apache finds that the rewrite `/goto/index.php?q=asdf` to `/goto/index.php?q=asdf` is 'no change'. On my change only a rewrite to `-` will be regarded as that. You'll have to look in your rewritelog to see exactly what is happening, and what decisions mod_rewrite makes. I can't guess what is happening on a certain OS/certain Apache version.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is due to non-presence of leading slash in target URL of this URL:

```
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now try this rule with leading slash before `goto`:

```
RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ /goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Now you will notice infinite looping error.**

**Reason** is that in the first case target URI does not begin with a slash. In that case `mod_rewrite` is smart enough to prevent infinite looping, as it detects that the original request of `goto/index.php` is the same as the internal rewrite to `goto/index.php` after first pass, therefore it won't perform the further rewrite with this message in `RewriteLog`:

```
[IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. Since the first rewritten URI up to (but not including) the query string is the same as the second rewritten URI up to the same point, it is being discarded as redundant. This is a feature of mod_rewrite designed to prevent infinite rewrite loops. If you replace your rule with:

RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ /goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

(notice the '/' in front of the substitution), assuming goto is in DocumentRoot, you will get the loop you expected.  This is because "/goto/index.php" (the result) is different from "goto/index.php" (the originally matched URI).

-- Original answer follows --

Can you verify that you are actually rewriting anything at all?  I ask because this is a rewrite from and to a relative path, and you have no RewriteBase directive in the .htaccess file.  Unless .htaccess is in the server's (or virtual host's) DocumentRoot directory, the rewrite engine requires RewriteBase to determine how to finish rewriting it.

Further, even if this is in the DocumentRoot directory (which is implied by the fact that the original URL to be rewritten is http://example.com/goto/foo), unless there is an AllowOverride directive giving FileInfo override permission, AND an Options directive specifying FollowSymLinks, effective for the directory, mod_rewrite directives in .htaccess files are ignored.

As for "reaching index.php" - without seeing the configuration, I really can't comment on why it's successfully serving a page, despite the lack of rewriting.  It could be that an ErrorDocument directive gives you a page that matches what you expect.  There could even be some rewriting rules in the server or virtual host configuration files that handle the case where /([^/]+)/index.php exists, rewriting requests that would otherwise generate a 404 error code to use the appropriate index.php file, instead.

References:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule - explains what conditions must be satisfied for rewriting to work.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride - documents the FileInfo keyword for the AllowOverride directive.

http://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess - describes several ways to manage rewriting to index.php

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Since the first rewritten URI up to (but not including) the query string is the same as the second rewritten URI up to the same point, it is being discarded as redundant.  This is a feature of mod_rewrite designed to prevent infinite rewrite loops.  If you replace your rule with 'RewriteRule ^goto/(.*)$ /goto/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]', instead (notice the '/' in front of the substitution), assuming goto is in DocumentRoot, you will get the loop you expected.

Comment: Can you revise your answer what you have written in last comment? This was the case here actually.